# How to fix the width of Dialogue box in Jquery UI to 60% of the window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using Jquery UI for a popup where I show a table which is being populated using Ajax call the script looks like this

```
 <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      show: {
        effect: "blind",
        duration: 1000
      },
      hide: {
        effect: "",
        duration: 1000
      }
    });

    $( "#opener" ).click(function() {
      $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
    });
  });
  </script>
```

And the HTML is pretty basic

```
    <div id="dialog" title="Preview" style="width:60%">
    SOme COntent here 
<table></table>
    </div>
```

When the popup appears the width is not increasing according to the table width . I want to fix the width of the popup to 60% of the window size

Comment: Where have you defines the div tag?

Comment: @R3tep bottom of the page ??

Comment: @R3tep yes before the </body>

Comment: Can you provide a live demo?

Comment: @R3tep umm okay let me try . The problem is Ajax call I have a select button inside the DIv on selecting that the table content changes but the width of the dialogue box remains same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to set the option width for the dialog box: (from here http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/)

`$("#dialog").dialog( "option", "width", '60%' );`

Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mykak5qx/